# Invalidate xml objects in RibbonUI

Tags: excel-2007, excel-2010, fluent-ribbon

I have a RibbonUI (Fluent Ribbon) in an Excel document that is 2007/2010 compliant.

I can successfully show/hide tabs/groups in the xml file when the excel file is loaded based on settings contained within the file.

If i wanted to expand the scope of this to the individual buttons, what would i need to incorporate for this to occur?

Would i need to extend the `getVisible` attribute to each button that would be conditionally visible?

Comment: Yes, you would need to extend that attribute/callback to each button.